# Extending paper-fab removes ripple effect

Tags: polymer

I have tried to extend `paper-fab` element but after that I lost ripple effect.

My code looks like this:

```
<polymer-element name="custom-fab" attributes="name count" extends="paper-fab">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host{
                margin: 5px;
            };
        </style>
        <shadow></shadow>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            count: 0,
            created: function() {
                this.name = {};
            }
        })
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was because my element was empty, I get the `ripple` effect again after adding some text to `label` attribute.

```
<custom-fab label="test"></custom-fab>
```